# Есть шапка написана на флексах?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть шапка написана на флексах.

Нужно, чтобы хедер прижался к верху `align-items`

```css
header {
 align-items: flex-start;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header_menu {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.callback {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <ul>
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <li>logo</li>
   </div>

   <div class="header_menu">
    <li class="about_active">about</li>
    <ul class="about_menu">
     <li>history</li>
     <li>command</li>
     <li>dreams</li>
    </ul>
    <li>portfolio</li>
    <li>servicies</li>
    <li>contacts</li>
   </div>
   
   <div class="callback">
    <li><button>callback</button></li>
   </div>
  </ul>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот шапка котрую нужно сделать на флексах

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду прижать - position: fixed? Так прижимайте, в чем проблема возникла?

Comment: нет aling-items

Comment: прислонить к верху

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас поняла, то вот так:

```css
header ul {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.about_active{
  position:relative
}
.about_menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header_menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.callback {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.about_menu {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <li>logo</li>
      </div>

      <div class="header_menu">
        <li class="about_active">about
          <ul class="about_menu">
            <li>history</li>
            <li>command</li>
            <li>dreams</li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>portfolio</li>
        <li>servicies</li>
        <li>contacts</li>
      </div>

      <div class="callback">
        <li><button>callback</button></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Применяйте дисплей флекс непосредственно к тому блоку в котором находятся выравниваемые вами элементы, а не к его родителю. То есть в вашем случае это - `ul`. Обнулила отступы у списка для наглядности.

Comment: да только 
history
command
dreams

должно быть под about....

Comment: дополните ваш вопрос, сделайте код наглядным, сделайте скрин или наборосок желаемого результата, что и как у вас "должно быть" знаете только вы

Comment: со скрином все наглядно и понятно, исправила код

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить

```
body  {  display: flex;    
flex-flow: column nowrap;   
justify-content: space-between;    
align-content: center;
```